# How to check if function inserted innerHTML correctly in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I'm writing code for myself to set values into an array based on which checkboxes are checked.

There is one function for setting innerHTML of the checkbox (checked or unchecked) and second one for changing the value of an array based on the condition if checkbox is checked or not.

The HTML code looks like this:

```js
function check(id) {
  if (id.innerHTML == "unchecked") {
    id.innerHTML = "checked";
  } else {
    id.innerHTML = "unchecked";
  }
}

function audiences() {
  var audiencesLength = [];
  var checkboxes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    checkboxes.push(document.getElementById("aud" + i).innerHTML)
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    if (checkboxes[j] != "unchecked") {
      switch (j) {
        case 0:
          audiencesLength[j] = 1;
          break;
        case 1:
          audiencesLength[j] = 3;
          break;
        case 2:
          audiencesLength[j] = 7;
          break;

      }
    } else {
      audiencesLength[j] = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<li class="checkboxes">
  <label class="checkbox-container">1
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="checkmark" id="aud0" onclick="check(this)">unchecked</span>
          </label>
  <label class="checkbox-container">3
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="checkmark" id="aud1" onclick="check(this)">unchecked</span>
          </label>
  <label class="checkbox-container">7
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="checkmark" id="aud2" onclick="check(this)">unchecked</span>
          </label>
</li>
```

It works until I start to check the checkboxes fast. Then some of them are correct and some of them have values "checked" when unchecked and some of them "unchecked" when checked.

Is there a way to prevent this? Or is there any problem in the code?

Thanks!

Comment: To start with, consider using informative variable names. `audiencesLength` is not a very good name for an array that sometimes contains HTMLInputElements and sometimes contains what looks to be numbers (not sure why you're mixing the two there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you only binding event to `span`, which won't work if you're click on `label` nor `input`. Instead, you should use `onchange` on `input`, this will affect both label of it and itself

```js
function check(element) {
    id = document.getElementById(element)
    if (id.innerHTML == "unchecked") {
        id.innerHTML = "checked";
    } else {
        id.innerHTML = "unchecked";
    }
}

function audiences() {
    var audiencesLength = [];
    var checkboxes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        checkboxes.push(document.getElementById("aud" + i).innerHTML)
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (checkboxes[j] != "unchecked") {
            switch (j) {
                case 0:
                    audiencesLength[j] = 1;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    audiencesLength[j] = 3;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    audiencesLength[j] = 7;
                    break;

            }
        } else {
            audiencesLength[j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<li class="checkboxes">
    <label class="checkbox-container">1
        <input onchange="check('aud0')" type="checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark" id="aud0">unchecked</span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-container">3
        <input onchange="check('aud1')" type="checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark" id="aud1">unchecked</span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-container">7
        <input onchange="check('aud2')" type="checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark" id="aud2">unchecked</span>
    </label>
</li>
```